# How does Gurobi expressions work on Python?

Tags: python, constraints, gurobi

I'm studying Gurobi (started this past month), and I tried to program a small Facility Location Problem. I get how the constraints work, but there is one which I'm having more difficulty, check the link:

[Demand of city 'j' that goes to the facility 'i' <= Capacity of facility 'k' installed in 'i'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5dIA.png)

I think I'll need to use the "LinExpr" function, but there is not much info on the documentation. If possible, are there any other sources for studying.

Here's what I've tried:

```
for i in facilities:
    for j in cities:
       exp_1 = d[j]*x[i,j]
    for c in cap:
       exp_2 = np.transpose(capacity)[i,c]*y[i,c]

m.addConstr(exp_1<=exp_2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use numpy functions like `np.transpose` on Gurobis variable objects. Instead, you have to write it directly with the help of gurobi functions. Assuming facilities, cities and capacities are appropriate lists, you can do it like this:

```
from gurobipy import quicksum, Model

m = Model()

# ... defining your lists and the variables d, x, cap

# Adding the constraints
for i in facilities:
    m.addConstr(quicksum(d[j]*x[i,j] for j in cities) <= quicksum(cap[k]*y[i,k] for k in capacities))
```

Comment: OH MY GOD, IT WORKED!
Thank you so much!